# How to include a library file(.dll/.lib) on livecode and use the functions on the library file

Tags: livecode

I am new to Livecode and still learning on the language. I have some problem on how to use a function inside the library I created(a .dll file) and call it on my livecode stack.

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have written a function inside the library to just display hello text if the button is pressed on my stack. And what I don't know how to do is to the function inside it on LiveCode.

Comment: You need to check out how to build an LCB file. LCB is Livecode builder. With that you can make an extension to read out your DLL file via LCS(livecode script). LCB can be used to interact with other languages like c, c++, javascript etcetera. Check the forums and lesson at livecode.com

Comment: You can't use any DLL with LiveCode. Your DLL needs to be designed and compiled specifically for LiveCode using LiveCode's externals SDK. (Externals and LCB are two completely different things).

Answer (score 0):

Here a guide, it's a wiki and you can update it: https://livecode.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_DLL